# printf + print param and values

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ksh + printf stat gap of print](https://superuser.com/questions/147590/ksh-printf-stat-gap-of-print)

I need to print the following values with printf as the follwoing around like this:

printf "[`date +%d"/"%b"/"%G"-"%T`] [WARN] $PARAM1 $PARAM2 $PARAM3

The required output:

[02/Jun/2010-11:08:42] [WARN]  val1....val2...val3

the gap between val1 to val2 and from val2 to val3 must be const gap not depend the length of the values

Comment: Your question was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949835/ksh-prinf-print-the-line-with-stat-gap/2951192#2951192).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify field widths for `printf`. Here are examples of printing numbers (spaces or zeros as prefix) and strings (left or right justified):

```
$ printf "[% 10d]" 1
[         1]

$ printf "[%010d]" 1
[0000000001]

$ printf "[%10s]" test
[      test]

$ printf "[%-10s]" test
[test      ]
```